# Is it possible to "Slim down" Json.NET's serialisation of objects?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an object i want to serialise, lets call it `JsonNameValuePair`. Heres what my code for `JsonNameValuePair` might look like:

```
public class JsonNameValuePair
{
    string Label { get; set; }

    string Value { get; set; }
}
```

If I were to serialise this to Json using `Json.NET` I would get something that looks like this:

```
{
    "label":"Name",
    "value":"Area 3"
}
```

but this is incredibly bulky for the amount of data I actually need, what I *really* need is the property names to be dropped, and the value of the property `Label` to be the "effective" name of the property `Value`. I am suffering from an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here?

Basically, what I want to be able to do in my code is

```
JsonNameValuePair myPair = new JsonNameValuePair()
{
    Label = "My Property",
    Value = "The Value"
}
```

and when I serialise this, I want my output to look like

```
{
    "My Property" : "The Value"
}
```

as this will make the code on the receiving end significantly easier, and will make the data calls smaller. How can this be achieved?

Comment: why not just use a dictionary on the server side, and then you get what you need?

Comment: It is generally advisable **not** to have dynamic key names in JSON because this makes it more difficult for clients who have to deserialise it - see e.g. https://github.com/WhiteHouse/api-standards#responses.

Comment: @Jamiec Ugh.. its so obvious it hurts.

Comment: @JosephEarl I understand the implications, but this is certainly a use case where that is not true

Comment: @JamesTrotter :) well done for spotting this was  XY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can by using a custom JsonConvert.
Check [this](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/) it is exactly what you need.